# ERROR : Sólo se puede especificar una expresión en la lista de selección cuando la subconsulta no se especifica con EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo una subconsulta pero al ejecutar me manda esta error

**Sólo se puede especificar una expresión en la lista de selección cuando la subconsulta no se especifica con EXISTS.**

les dejo acá la consulta

```
SELECT m.mes,tp.Cod_Area,tp.Cod_Puesto,Puesto, me.nom_emp,TB.Tipo_Benef,Monto,Fecha_Gestion,
   (SELECT TB2.Tipo_Benef, SUM (Monto) FROM Tabla_Principal AS tp2  INNER JOIN Tipo_Beneficio AS tb2 ON TB2.Id=TP2.Tipo_Benef GROUP BY TB2.Tipo_Benef )
       FROM Tabla_Principal AS tp
        INNER JOIN Mes AS m ON M.id=TP.mes
        INNER JOIN Tipo_Beneficio AS tb ON TB.Id=TP.Tipo_Benef
        INNER JOIN Maestro_Empl AS me ON me.No_emp = tp.No_emp
```

ps veran lo que deseo el total de cada uno de los Tipo_Benef
que me salga en una columna al final por ejemplo el total de LENTES,AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA no se si me entienden
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
le agradezco su respuesta de antemano

Comment: Bueno, el mensaje del error en este caso es bastante claro. Cuando tú usas una subquery como una columna más en tu `SELECT` original, entonces esta subquery debe entregar un solo valor por cada fila; y tu subconsulta entrega más de una

Comment: Si, mas allá de una explicación del error, deseas saber cómo solucionarlo, sería bueno que explicaras el resultado que pretendes obtener. Sospecho que no hay necesidad de una subconsulta en absoluto.

Comment: es que veran  en la consulta principal me muestra todos los pero no me los suma los montos ,entonces hago un subconsulta para que sume los monto y me agrelos monto ya sumado en la otra consulta

Comment: Pero el resultado que quieres no tiene mucho que ver con el código que pusiste. Es más, las columnas LENTES y AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA son de otra pregunta que hiciste

Comment: @norma, puedes usar [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) para [crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave sqlfiddle se cae mucho últimamente, te recomiendo probar [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk)

Comment: @Lamak no lo sabía, gracias, ojalá que norma también vea tu comentario, ayudaría muchísimo para aclarar su pregunta.

Comment: Se que tiene algún tiempo esta pregunta, pero el problema es que en la subconsulta dolo debes especificar una columna en el select, la subconsulta solo debe devolver una sola columna en el select.

Answer (score 1):

> es que veran en la consulta principal me muestra todos los pero no me los suma los montos ,entonces hago un subconsulta para que sume los monto y me agrelos monto ya sumado en la otra consulta

No está 100% claro, pero me parece que lo que buscas es la función ventana `SUM()`:

```
SELECT m.mes,tp.Cod_Area,tp.Cod_Puesto,Puesto, me.nom_emp,TB.Tipo_Benef,Monto,Fecha_Gestion,
       SUM(Monto) OVER (PARTITION BY TB.Tipo_Benef) AS sum_monto
FROM Tabla_Principal AS tp
INNER JOIN Mes AS m ON M.id=TP.mes
INNER JOIN Tipo_Beneficio AS tb ON TB.Id=TP.Tipo_Benef
INNER JOIN Maestro_Empl AS me ON me.No_emp = tp.No_emp
```

Comment: Suena como lo que el op necesita

Comment: @Lamak: La verdad es que no estoy tan seguro... La subconsulta de OP está un poco rara. No solo tiene el problema de devolver mas de una columna, pero probablemente devuelve más de un registro también ya que no veo ninguna condición que haga referencia a la parte principal de la consulta para filtrar los datos. Norma: si esto no es lo que buscas, tendrás que ser más explícito por medio de ejemplos concretos de los datos que tienes y el resultado deseado.

Comment: edite la pregunta para ver si me logro entender

Comment: @norma: No se entiende. no veo la relación entre la imagen que incluístes y la consulta que tienes.

Comment: es que por medio de la consulta saco los totales y en la imagen muestro los totales por ejemplo quiero sumar todo los que tengan lentes para que me den un total ejemplo LENTES 470 sin importa si los nombre de empleados son diferente solo deso sumar los tipo_benef

Comment: El problema con este tipo de preguntas de consultas SQL es que a veces las palabras solamante no transmiten bien toda la idea. De allí la utilidad de que comuniques claramente usando un ejemplo con datos **concretos** (en formato tabular), y que incluya lo siguiente: 1) Ejemplo **concreto** de los datos antes de hacer la consulta 2) Ejemplo **concreto** con datos del resultado deseado de la consulta.